# How to use async in sync code?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Async method (works fine in async code):

```
public async Task<ServiceResult<Config>> GetConfigAsync(string id)
        {
            var entity = await _entityRepo.FindAsync(t => t.Id == id);
            if (entity == null) throw new Exception($"entity Id {id} is invalid");
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(entity.Config);
            return new ServiceResult<Config>(result);
        }
```

And I try to call it from sync code:

```
var configTask = _configurationService.GetConfigAsync(id);
var config = configTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

I can't see any issue, so it I just stuck.

What I do wrong?

Comment: What makes you think it is not working?

Comment: compiler error? runtime exception?

Comment: Is the sync code being called from async code? If so you have a context deadlock. To test add `ConfigureAwait`:  `var entity = await _entityRepo.FindAsync(t => t.Id == id).ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: It just stuck. no issues API call just wait and timeout

Comment: **[Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)**

Comment: can you break the debugger to see where it is stuck - on the `GetResult` call?

Comment: @igor I don't want change GetConfigAsync method. It is works fine in async code

Comment: Did you try stepping in the debugger?  Are you sure where it's stuck?

Comment: @JoelFan If I debug it. It works.